# callback function as a parameter in a library API

Tags: c#

I am writing a FTP client library. My get function should take the following parameters: `(Server IP, remotefilename, clientfilename, Applications_callback_function)`

I have written the library to do the get functionality without the `Applications_callback_function` parameter.

Expectation is to write the get API with `Applications_callback_function` parameter and call the callback function with the result once the file transfer completes and also put the result in to `EventArgs`.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: You can do this using a delegate for the callback parameter. Assuming the library is written in C#...

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a delegate to your `get` method. Try this:

```
function Get(string ServerIP, string, remotefilename, string clientfilename, Action<YourResponseType> Applications_callback_function)
{
    // your logic...
    Applications_callback_function(data_from_request);
}
```

Or if the response is not of a single type:

```
function Get<T>(string ServerIP, string remotefilename, string clientfilename, Action<T> Applications_callback_function)
{
    // your logic...
    Applications_callback_function(data_from_request);
}

// caller...
Get<ResponseType>("127.0.0.1", "foo.txt", "bar.txt", myHandler);

function myHandler(ResponseType data) 
{
   // handle response...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!I like to have asynchronous behaviour in application side. I think above code works synchronously, which will make the application to wait for Get function's response.

Comment: Well it would have to, if you're going to pass the data from the request to the callback?

Comment: Hi Rory McCrossan, I like to pass the result of Get function to Callback function to update the application(i.e SUCCESS/ FAILURE). I like to have asynchrous benahviour so that application can continue on other request/operations.

Comment: You could process your FTP requests in a separate thread, assuming your FTP library doesn't already have some method of async. You may be better asking a new question if you need more detail.